# Can I Create a variable that is useful in SQL Statement and PL SQL Script as well?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have  defined a variable in sql script as below:

```
DEFINE USER_NAME="TEST_DB";
DEFINE PASSWORD="abc";
```

Now in my script I have few sql statement where I can use above variable with &USER_NAME and it's serve my purpose.
Now I have PL SQL block also:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
CONST_MASTER_USER varchar2(100) := 'TEST_DB';
-- FEW CODE
END
```

Now I want to use USER_NAME variable in this PL/SQL Block, but when I replace 'TEST_DB' with &USER_NAME, SQL Developer gives me following error:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'TEST_DB' must be declared
```

As I am not expert in SQL, do we have any solution where we can define a variable once and use it in SQL as well as PLSQL statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you removed the quotes, which are still needed with substitution variables:

```
DECLARE
   CONST_MASTER_USER varchar2(100) := '&USER_NAME.';
BEGIN
-- FEW CODE
END
```

Comment: Thanks @tony...! Can you please tell me why we need to put . (dot) after the variable name?

Comment: It is optional here but I always do it as it is sometimes necessary to avoid ambiguity e.g. `'&VAR.XXX' ` versus `&VARX.XX'`